A magrittr pipe that adds side-effect functionality to %>%
I would like to make a custom magrittr pipe that is essentially the same as %>%, but has some extra functionality added to it, as a side effect. E.g. print some information, tabulate or plot the intermediate results or update a progress bar.
Looking around if something like this exists, I found the tee pipe %T>% that can be used to add a statement in the pipeline itself ("inline" so to speak). I also found this answer that specifies %V%, to do nothing with the inputs and just pass it along, to add some inline side effect that is unrelated to the pipe contents.
Neither of these is what I am looking for. I want a custom function to specify a pipe that can replace a %>% (or a |>) without change of pipe functionality.
I wonder if this can be done easily.

Not quite what you're asking, but you might be interested in trying the breakerofchains addin if you want to add some "print midway through the chain" functionality. https://github.com/MilesMcBain/breakerofchains

I suspect I've misunderstood, but I use the tee pipe for any 'side effects' that I want in my pipelines like tabling data or precursory plotting; what functionality are you looking for that you don't get from the tee pipe @Ralph?

The tee pipe needs an extra inline statement. I want to just be able to replace %>% by a new pipe that does something else besides continuing its normal function.

%>% is a function in magrittr, so it's possible to look at the source code and modify it to add extra functionality. For example to define a function that prints the head of the first argument:
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

#Define a new function based on `%>%`
`%P%` <- function (lhs, rhs) 
{
  print(head(lhs))  #Add in some extra functionality
  lhs <- substitute(lhs)
  rhs <- substitute(rhs)
  kind <- 1L
  env <- parent.frame()
  lazy <- TRUE
  .External2(magrittr:::magrittr_pipe)
}


iris %P% group_by(Species) %P% summarise(Petal.Width = mean(Petal.Width))

# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
# # Groups:   Species [1]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
# 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
# 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
# Species    Petal.Width
# <fct>            <dbl>
# 1 setosa           0.246
# 2 versicolor       1.33 
# 3 virginica        2.03 

Note that the source code for the pipe can be found with
`%>%`


This works. I tried this before, but couldn't get it to work, because I needed to add magrittr::: before magrittr_pipe in the source code apparently.

Is a more elegant solution also possible by not just copying the source code? Maybe just referencing %>% somehow? There was a previous answer from someone before but it has been retracted because it didn't work.
